# GRUB background resolution and text?

Tags: 11.10, grub2, resolution, desktop-background

I want to know my GRUB resolution ? and what if I set the GRUB background image that is higher or lower resolution than current grub resolution , do I have to resize it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I have found to manage the GRUB screen / resolution / text-size is to use "Grub_Customizer"

It works for GRUB and BURG both

Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

then you can fully manage the GRUB screen

[image]

[source](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with "BlueXrider", however I could not get the ppa listed to work, so this is the one I would use:

ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

it comes from the person that makes or manages the "Grub Customizer"

(Follow the same instructions from 'BlueXrider', just change the ppa in the instructions.)