# How to install startupmanager in 12.04?

Tags: installation

I installed 12.04 today. I have two hard disks and separate OS. I want to install startupmanager.

I previously installed startupmanager in 11.10 for dual hard disk booting with XP but after 12.04 installation (fresh installation), startupmanager was not found in Software Center.

How do I install startupmanager on 12.04?

Answer (score 10):

Startupmanager no longer exists in the 12.04 repositories.

This application has been superseded by much better tools

You can use excellent alternatives (but not in the official repositories):

- [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer?field.series_filter=precise)

---

If you are looking about how to customise certain aspects of grub then there are great questions here on Ask Ubuntu:

1. [Decrease GRUB timeout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43020/decrease-grub-timeout/43022#43022)
2. [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/52990#52990)
3. [GRUB background resolution and text?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118995/grub-background-resolution-and-text)
4. [Change boot entry names and grub background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115432/change-boot-entry-names-and-grub-background)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, startup manager is removed from official repository of 12.04.

From [StartUp-Manager is dead](https://launchpad.net/startup-manager/+announcement/8300):

> So, i have finally come to the decision to officially stop development
>   of this application.
>
> For personal reasons, i have not kept up with Ubuntu much lately. I
>   was meaning to get back to this project someday, even said at one
>   point that there will be a SUM2. Sorry about that, i have realized now
>   that it will not happen.
>
> The decision to make this announcement came today when reading a bug
>   report about some changes with the latest versions of grub. When
>   trying to figure out how to adapt to these changes, i came across
>   another app: Grub Customizer. After testing that app, i realized that
>   updating SUM would just be a duplication of work at this point. So
>   check that app out instead, it seems to work well. Of course, if
>   anyone feel like taking over this project anyway, just contact me.
>
> Thanks all for using and contributing to StartUp-Manager in the past

Answer (score 0):

How about installing threw grub?

```
sudo apt-get install startupmanager
```

Well, I never rely upon software center as it does not list all the packages I wanted. Maybe this link ould help you in either way:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager#Installation_Instructions

Comment: some errors on terminalReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package startupmanager is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'startupmanager' has no installation candidate

Comment: [Link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=startupmanager). Go here and choose your version of ubuntu and install the package you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

These instructions are simple and works well: [HOWTO: Grub Customizer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.