# startup manager in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, startupmanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to install startupmanager in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131976/how-to-install-startupmanager-in-12-04)

I am unable to find start up manager in the repos for ubuntu 12.04 amd64. I use a core i3 2nd generation with 6gb ram. I did a clean install of 12.04 amd64.

Has start up manager been withdrawn in 12.04 ?

Thanks in advance.

ragv